# How to remove "continue;"?

Tags: c++, continue

I have this c++ program that tries to remove vowels from a char array. This works, but I want to do this without `continue;`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {


    char s[21],afterElimination[19],vowels[] = "aeiou";
    cin.get(s,20);
    int i, n = strlen(s),VowelPos = -1,h = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (strchr(vowels,s[i])) {
            if(VowelPos == -1) {
                VowelPos = i;
                continue;
            } 
            VowelPos = i - 1;
        }
        afterElimination[h++] = s[i];

    }
    afterElimination[h] = NULL;
    strcpy(afterElimination + VowelPos, afterElimination + VowelPos + 1);

    cout<<afterElimination;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if this was documented a little. As it stands there's not much clarify into what's going on.

Comment: sorry exaggerated, I know what `vocale` is ;)

Comment: @user463035818 and you can easily use google translate to figure out the meaning of `dupa`.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without "continue"? Context can be helpful.

Comment: *How to remove continue* -- Use `std::remove_if` and a lambda.

Comment: Now it is in english!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work though: input: `aeiou`, output: `eio`.

Comment: Why do you want to remove `continue`, though? `continue` and `break` are valuable tools for loop control, and using them wisely makes the code easier to understand and reason about.

Comment: I want to do this without continue(I know continue works) because my teacher doesn't learned  us this statement, and she will say: "copy&paste"!

Comment: What have you learned than?

Comment: @SergeyA I disagree. Generally, `continue` and `break` are indicative of structural or logic problems and are *difficult* to reason about because they are essentially `goto`s in control flow. Usually, the `if` logic can be better organized or a helper function can be written.

Comment: Why are you using char arrays, strlen(), etc.?  Are you really learning C++?

Comment: With continue:
input: studio
output: std
It works :)

Comment: @ggorlen disagree in the most strong terms. Absent `continue` code becomes unnecessary scoped (an extra scope when continue would do) and absent `break` loop conditions suddenly has another boolean check on it for no reason. I do not understand why people would not use them, are you also against early return in functions?

Comment: Your basic problem is that you are writing C, not C++.

Comment: School basics! :(

Comment: Do you know what `continue` does? Did you write such code? If so, what, exactly, is the difficulty of writing it without `continue`?

Comment: I can't use only char arrays and some functions: `stycpy`, `strncpy`, `strlen`, `strchr`, `strstr`, `strcat`

Comment: Continue "reloop" the while statement, no?

Comment: @Bogdan Just to rant -- your school is already teaching you `C` coding instead of `C++`, and then waste more of your time (and the other student's time) doing a worthless assignment like this (trying to get rid of `continue`).  Come on, is this the state of C++ ediucttion these days?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, it ignores the rest of the loop body and begins another iteration, including evaluating the iteration statement (for a `for` loop) and evaluating the loop condition.

Comment: @Bogdan "_Continue "reloop" the while statement, no?_" So, having that in mind, can't you reorder the conditional operations, in a way, that `continue` is not needed? Side note. You stated, tat your program "_tries to remove vowels from a char array._", and that it "works", yet, somehow, when given input "Hello world!", it outputs "Hllo wrld!" Isn't "o" an vowel? [Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SGYtQvMigDB7vbEs).

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to remove `continue` from the loop.  What you need is two indexes in your loop.  One for the position in the source array and one for the position in the array to copy to.  Then you put the copy operation inside the if statement so if there is no copy you do nothing to go to the next iteration.  That would make you loop look like

```
for (int source_index = 0, copy_index = 0; source_index < n; ++source_index) { // increment source_index always
    if (!strchr(vowels,s[i])) {
        // this isn't a vowel so copy and increment copy_index
        afterElimination[copy_index++] = s[i];
    }
    // now this is the continue but we don't need to say it
}
```

Comment: @Bogdan now your teacher wont say "copy&paste" ? In fact it does not really matter where you get the code from, just make sure you understand it :P

Comment: You should just check `s[source_index]` in your `for` condition. Computing the length means you iterate the string twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical approach to filtering letters from a given string.

```
#include <string.h>

char s[20] = "something";
char no_vowels[20] = {0};

int i = 0;
int j = 0;
const char *vowels = "aeiou";
while (s[i]) {
  if (!strchr(vowels, s[i])) {
    no_vowels[j] = s[i];
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

Here's a working [example](https://repl.it/repls/WhisperedUncommonRobodoc).

Comment: @Bogdan You're welcome. Feel free to up vote and / or select helpful answers.